# Haxe/C++ Compiiling "Fatal error: exception Failure("File not found compile.hxml")"

Tags: c++, haxe

I am writing my first program on Haxe. I followed the [instructions on the site](http://old.haxe.org/doc/start/cpp) for writing C++ code for Haxe but when I try to compile my program it says "*Fatal error: exception Failure("File not found compile.hxml*".

I typed "*haxe compile.hxml*" on the command prompt to compile my program.

I am using Sublime Editor to write the programs.

In my *test.hx* I have

```
class Test 
{
    static function main() 
    {
        trace("Hello there");
    }
}
```

In *compile.hxml* I have

```
-cpp cpp
-debug
-main Test
-D HXCPP_M64
```

I am using Windows 8, 64 bit.

Can you help me?

Comment: I'd rather use [the most recent docs](http://haxe.org/documentation/introduction/language-introduction.html) if in doubt.

Comment: test.hx should be Test.hx, notice the upper-case is needed.